# (Python Tkinter) Why did my buttons stop appearing when I tried to add a scrollbar?

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

I was trying to write a program that has each individual photo from a file shown as a `Button`, which worked up until I tried to add a `Scrollbar` to the `Canvas` in case there were more buttons than the screen could fit. But for some reason, all the buttons disappeared off the screen, and the scrollbar would be small, in the middle of the screen and not at all where I wanted it. The lines I used for making the scrollbar worked in a different part of the program before, but now they are not. I included pictures of what it looks like before and after the change[image: Before][image: After]

```
photoMenu=tk.Tk()
photoMenu.title("Insta-Copy")
photoMenu.geometry("1720x1080")
photoMenu.resizable(0,0)

photoCanvas=tk.Canvas(photoMenu,width=1720,height=900)
vsb=tk.Scrollbar(photoCanvas)
vsb.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)

photoCanvas.config(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)

photoCanvas.pack()
vsb.config(command=photoCanvas.yview)

x=-100
y=50
y2=165

for file in pathList:
    x+=150

    fileName=file.replace(sourceDirectory+"/","")
    with open ("InstaCopyFiles.txt") as fileList:
        if file in fileList.read(): #File has already been copied before
           tk.Label(photoCanvas,text=fileName,fg="red").place(x=x,y=y2)
        else:
           tk.Label(photoCanvas,text=fileName).place(x=x,y=y2)


     photoButton=tk.Button(photoCanvas,image=photo,command=partial(photoSelected,file))
     photoButton.image=photo    
     photoButton.place(x=x,y=y)

     if x>=1500:
         x=-100
         y+=140
         y2+=140
```

Answer (score 0):

They disappeared because you put the scrollbar inside the canvas. That, combined with the fact you didn't use any options when calling `pack`, cause the canvas to shrink to fit the scrollbar.

It's not normal to put scrollbars inside the canvas. Typically you would use a frame, and make both the canvas and the scrollbars children of the frame.

Also, it's a bit unusual to put the image in a label and then call `place` on the label to put it inside a canvas. The canvas natively supports images, so you can put them directly on the canvas. If you use `place`, you won't be able to scroll the images because you can only scroll canvas items (items created with the `create_*` methods).